# How to display data in child component differently for different elements of a table in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

I want to display different data of each element in my table in vuejs

I have used props and I am able to display the data of the table created via the b-table tag. But I am unable to display data differently for each element inside the table. Some code might be easy for me to make you understand my problem

```
<div class="card-body" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
                <loader v-if="loading" />
                <b-table v-else
                         @row-selected="onRowClick"
                         bordered
                         responsive
                         stacked="md"
                         :items="items"
                         :fields="fields"
                         :current-page="currentPage"
                         :per-page="perPage"
                         :filter="filter"
                         @filtered="onFiltered"
                         selectable
                         :select-mode="'single'">
                    <template v-slot:cell(show_details)="row">
                        <b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails" class="mr-2">
                            {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Details
                        </b-button>

                    </template>

                    <template v-slot:row-details="row">
                        <b-card>
                            <b-row class="mb-2">
                                <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Age:</b></b-col>
                                <b-col>{{items[0].companyIdentifier}}</b-col>
                            </b-row>

                            <b-row class="mb-2">
                                <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Is Active:</b></b-col>
                                <b-col>active</b-col>
                            </b-row>

                            <b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails">Hide Details</b-button>
                        </b-card>
                    </template>
                </b-table>

            </div>
```

For the b-table I am displaying the data using the items field which is declared as a prop below and is coming from the parent. But below, I am unable to show the data inside the b-card.

Comment: Can you share the `js` code as well? It would seem the card and table are under two different template tags so if they are part of different child components, then passing data to b-table won't reflect on b-card.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with the help of scoped slots in bootstrap vue table.

Answer (score 0):

I think data inside `b-card` show be rendered with `row.item.companyIdentifier`.
 instead. `items[0].companyIdentifier` will always be the same as first item.

```
<template v-slot:row-details="row">
  <b-card>
      <b-row class="mb-2">
          <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Age:</b></b-col>
          <b-col>{{row.items.companyIdentifier}}</b-col>
      </b-row>

      <b-row class="mb-2">
          <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Is Active:</b></b-col>
          <b-col>active</b-col>
      </b-row>

      <b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails">Hide Details</b-button>
  </b-card>
</template>
```